# Problems Creating Auth User in ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a VS Project I built, basically just and ASP.NET Core 5 Web Site with local Auth enabled. I can register local users, then login to them no problem.  However, when I try to create a user programmatically, with the code below,I know the user is created because I can view it in SQL, however when I try and login, I get a "login access no allowed" error.

1. Am I somehow not creating the user correctly?
2. How can I debug this to see what is not validating?

   ```
   public static async Task SeedDefaultUserAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
   {
       string testUser = "user999";
       var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(testUser);

       if (user == null)
       {
           user = new ApplicationUser()
           {
               Email = testUser + "@gmail.com",
               UserName = testUser,
               EmailConfirmed = true,
               LockoutEnabled = false,
           };

           await userManager.CreateAsync(user, "Abc123@");
           Console.WriteLine("user: " + testUser + " available with password Abc123@.");
       }

       if (user == null)
       {
           throw new Exception("The password is probably not strong enough!");
       }
   }
   ```

I've even tried sending myself a password reset link, reset the password and I still get the login error.

Comment: Add your project ConfigureServices to your question

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, when you login in asp.net core identity it will called the CanSignInAsync method to check the user could signin or not.

If user doesn't pass , it will throw the "login access no allowed" error.

More details, you could refer to below source codes:

```
    protected virtual async Task<SignInResult> PreSignInCheck(TUser user)
    {
        if (!await CanSignInAsync(user))
        {
            return SignInResult.NotAllowed;
        }
        if (await IsLockedOut(user))
        {
            return await LockedOut(user);
        }
        return null;
    }



   public virtual async Task<bool> CanSignInAsync(TUser user)
    {
        if (Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail && !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user)))
        {
            Logger.LogWarning(0, "User cannot sign in without a confirmed email.");
            return false;
        }
        if (Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber && !(await UserManager.IsPhoneNumberConfirmedAsync(user)))
        {
            Logger.LogWarning(1, "User cannot sign in without a confirmed phone number.");
            return false;
        }
        if (Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount && !(await _confirmation.IsConfirmedAsync(UserManager, user)))
        {
            Logger.LogWarning(4, "User cannot sign in without a confirmed account.");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

So I suggest you could check your startup.cs to make sure you have set the phone or RequireConfirmedAccount to false like below, if you have enabled other required information you should set it in your application.

Besides, by default the username is also a Email format, please modify your codes to set username to  Email also. `UserName = testUser + "@gmail.com",`

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options =>
        { options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;

        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @BrandoZhang, I can't resolve TUser. Is there a nuget package that supports that?  Also, is there any docs with an example I can lookat?

Comment: Also, having trouble finding rules on username and it has to be email. please provide link to that if you have it

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a custom signinmanager class? If this is your requirement, I suggest you could refer to this [source codes](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/1ca039fd14d2fc1166f2c589fbc510ab315cb18b/src/Identity/Core/src/SignInManager.cs).  Besides, there is no article show that the user name should be Email, I just tell you that the default username is as same as the Email.

Comment: Thanks @BrandoZhang, it sounds like, based on line 146 of the source code you mention, that there is no production way to tell the user what the problem is. Am I understanding that correctly? That is, just a development time log message.

Comment: Yes, we need check the log to see why it failed.